# How to do explode and keep a fair proportion of number value for each new row Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-explode

I have this dataframe:

```
           A  B 
0  [0, 1, 2]  1 
1        foo  1 
2     [3, 4]  1
```

I would like to use explode function for column "A" and then to keep right and fair proportion for each exploded row in case with column "B" . So the result should look like this:

```
     A  B 
0    0  0.33
0    1  0.33
0    2  0.33
1  foo  1 
2    3  0.5 
2    4  0.5
```

Would this be possible with the explode function? I would manage to come to this result with `for row in data.itertuples():` but the for loop is so slow in case with large dataframe. So do you have idea how to solve this with explode or with some other fast way?

I would be very grateful with any help.

Comment: `edf = df.explode("A"); edf.B = edf.groupby(edf.index).B.transform("size").rdiv(1)`. You didn't show your full attempt as a code,  so I don't attempt to explain. Also, idk if this is fast enough for you :)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks anyway. I did not manage to do much with the problem unless I used the for cycle. I'm not sure if its worth to publish this attempt with the for loop to this post when its not connected in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `explode` "A"; then `groupby` the index and `transform` `count` method (to count the number of each index) and divide the elements in `'B'` by their corresponding index count.

```
out = df.explode('A')
out['B'] /= out['B'].groupby(level=0).transform('count')
```

Output:

```
     A         B
0    0  0.333333
0    1  0.333333
0    2  0.333333
1  foo  1.000000
2    3  0.500000
2    4  0.500000
```

Comment: So much nicer than my answer! :P

Answer (score 2):

Create a boolean mask which indicates rows where `A` holds a list:

```
mask = df['A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list))
```

Prepopulate a new column of denominators with the integer 1 (to leave division by these values unchanged):

```
df['denom'] = 1
```

For each row where `A` is a list, overwrite the value of `B` with the length of the list:

```
df.loc[mask, 'denom'] = df['A'].str.len()
```

Explode column `A`, compute the new value of `B`, and drop `denom`:

```
res = df.explode('A').reset_index(drop=True)
res['B'] = res['B'] / res['denom']
res = res.drop(columns='denom')
```

Result:

```
print(res)
     A         B
0    0  0.333333
1    1  0.333333
2    2  0.333333
3  foo  1.000000
4    3  0.500000
5    4  0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode`, then `groupby`+`apply`:

```
(df.explode('A')
   .assign(B=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0)['B'].apply(lambda s:s/len(s)))
)
```

output:

```
     A         B
0    0  0.333333
0    1  0.333333
0    2  0.333333
1  foo  1.000000
2    4  0.500000
2    5  0.500000
```

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[0,1,2], 'foo', [4,5]],
                   'B': [1,1,1]})
```

Comment: The output you display doesn't match the one your code yields.

Comment: I like it is one line answer. However the part of your answer where is ...B=... How can I put there a variable so this line of code would be dynamic and possible to use it inside a function?

Comment: @kvetjo You can use a dictionary in `assign`: `assign(**{'B': lambda ...})`, now the column name is a string and dynamic ;)