# How to explode a list column and proportionally split an integer column in python polars?

Tags: python, pivot, python-polars

I have a dataset that includes item types and quantities of each item, except that some rows of the item type column contain lists of types instead of a single type. I want to explode the list of types into separate rows and split the quantities proportionally.

In pandas, I would typically explode and then groupby the index, similar to [the process described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70745966/how-to-do-explode-and-keep-a-fair-proportion-of-number-value-for-each-new-row-pa) (the sample data shown on that page is analogous to the data I'm working with).

I can always create my own index in the polars dataframe, or convert to and back from Pandas in chucks that fit in memory, but is there a more better way to do this in Polars?

### Edits:

There seemed to be some confusion in the comments, so for clarity, I have data shaped like so:

```
┌───────────────────┬─────┐
│ cat               ┆ qty │
│ ---               ┆ --- │
│ list[str]         ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════════════╪═════╡
│ ["green", "blue"] ┆ 23  │
│ ["green"]         ┆ 23  │
│ ["red"]           ┆ 4   │
│ ["blue"]          ┆ 5   │
│ ["red", "blue"]   ┆ 15  │
└───────────────────┴─────┘
```

And I want:

```
┌───────┬──────┐
│ cat   ┆ qty  │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ f64  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ green ┆ 11.5 │
│ blue  ┆ 11.5 │
│ green ┆ 23.0 │
│ red   ┆ 4.0  │
│ blue  ┆ 5.0  │
│ red   ┆ 7.5  │
│ blue  ┆ 7.5  │
└───────┴──────┘
```

Which I can get with:

```
#convert to pandas
df_out = df.to_pandas()
#exploding cats
df_out = df_out.explode('cat')
#correct for multiplied quantity column
df_out['qty'] /= df_out['qty'].groupby(level=0).transform('count')
#back to polars
df_out = pl.DataFrame(df_out)
#print
print(df_out)
```

One could also do it with a script similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143341/explode-a-polars-dataframe-column-without-duplicating-other-column-values/78143635) (thanks to @Henricks for finding that article!).

But I imagine there's a much better way to do this? Ideally in a way that can be done in lazy mode and without creating a new column to serve as a pseudo-index? But I haven't come up with anything that works. Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you provided code to produce an example dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143341/explode-a-polars-dataframe-column-without-duplicating-other-column-values/78143635) related question.

Comment: I updated the OP for clarity, although the first link in the OP suffices to explain the situation. The related question you posted is effectively what I had in mind when I said I could create my own index in the dataframe before doing this operation. If that's the best way to do it, so be it, but it seems like there should be a means of doing the job without creating a new column just for this operation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've provided an answer that doesn't rely on creating an extra column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the pandas approach, you can divide *qty* by the number of elements in the corresponding *cat* list.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col("qty") / pl.col("cat").list.len())
    .explode("cat")
)
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ cat   ┆ qty  │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ f64  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ green ┆ 11.5 │
│ blue  ┆ 11.5 │
│ green ┆ 23.0 │
│ red   ┆ 4.0  │
│ blue  ┆ 5.0  │
│ red   ┆ 7.5  │
│ blue  ┆ 7.5  │
└───────┴──────┘
```

**Note.** In contrast to pandas, we perform this operation *before* exploding the list column (to still have access to the length of the lists).

Comment: i KNEW it was going to be obvious (you know, once someone spoon-fed it to me) ;). Thanks!