# Explode a polars DataFrame column without duplicating other column values

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python, python-polars

As a minimum example, let's say we have next polars.DataFrame:

`df = pl.DataFrame({"sub_id": [1,2,3], "engagement": ["one:one,two:two", "one:two,two:one", "one:one"], "total_duration": [123, 456, 789]})`

| sub_id | engagement | total_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one:one,two:two | 123 |
| 2 | one:two,two:one | 456 |
| 3 | one:one | 789 |

then, we explode "engagement" column

`df = df.with_columns(pl.col("engagement").str.split(",")).explode("engagement")`

and receive:

| sub_id | engagement | total_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one:one | 123 |
| 1 | two:two | 123 |
| 2 | one:two | 456 |
| 2 | two:one | 456 |
| 3 | one:one | 789 |

For visualization I use Plotly, and code would be following:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x="sub_id", y="total_duration", color="engagement")
fig.show()
```

Resulting plot:

[image: Resulting plot]

Now it basically means that subscribers 1 and 2 have their total_duration (total watched time) doubled.
How could I remain total_duration per sub, but leaving engagement groups as shown on the plot legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option to handle this in polars would be to split `total_duration` equally between engagement rows within `sub_id`. For this, we simply divide `total_duration` by the number of rows of the given `sub_id`.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("engagement").str.split(",")
    )
    .explode("engagement")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("total_duration") / pl.len().over("sub_id")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ sub_id ┆ engagement ┆ total_duration │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ i64    ┆ str        ┆ f64            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ one:one    ┆ 61.5           │
│ 1      ┆ two:two    ┆ 61.5           │
│ 2      ┆ one:two    ┆ 228.0          │
│ 2      ┆ two:one    ┆ 228.0          │
│ 3      ┆ one:one    ┆ 789.0          │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to have your `total_duration` to be split equally between `engagement` within `sub_id`, you could adjust it before exploding:

```py
(
    df.with_columns(pl.col('engagement').str.split(','))
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('total_duration') / pl.col('engagement').list.len(),
    ).explode('engagement')
)

┌────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ sub_id ┆ engagement ┆ total_duration │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ i64    ┆ str        ┆ f64            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ one:one    ┆ 61.5           │
│ 1      ┆ two:two    ┆ 61.5           │
│ 2      ┆ one:two    ┆ 228.0          │
│ 2      ┆ two:one    ┆ 228.0          │
│ 3      ┆ one:one    ┆ 789.0          │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘
```